# Power BI write back to sql source

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is it possible to write data back to sql server source without using power apps in power BI?

If yes how

Thanks

Comment: No, its not possible. You need some sort of Power App to write anything back to the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Let's suppose you have a MS SQL server named `myserver`, DB called `newtest` and a sql table called `Table_1`. `Table_1` consists of one column called `Email`.

You intend to write a query that generates an email in power bi and you desire to write back that value in the table.

This is how you do it

```
let
  Source   = Sql.Database("myserver", "newtest"), 
  emailVal = "2@xyz.com", 
  Custom1  = "INSERT INTO [newtest].[dbo].[Table_1] (Email) VALUES('" & emailVal & "')", 
  Custom2  = Value.NativeQuery(Source, Custom1)
in
  Custom2
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. However what visual can i use to write back in such a way that the end user can type in the email address and that will right back to the table

Comment: I have my doubts whether that is going to happen at all. None of the Visuals have the option of using a parameter input from the end user which in turn goes into a power query and writes back the values in a SQL DB table. As far as I know, none of the visuals has a power query as an option.

Comment: Moreover, each of these end users need to have write access to the server itself. What you can do though, create an excel in sharepoint where the end users can give their input and you can create a connection in your power query to read those values from the sharepoint and have them fed into the power query as parameters for SQL insert. It can run from the power bi service even.