# Use TRUNCATE TABLE against SQL Server in Power Query?

Tags: sql-server, powerquery

I'd like to use Microsoft Power Query to truncate a SQL Server table.

I wrote the M-Query code below, using the technique in [Power BI write back to sql source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68269301/power-bi-write-back-to-sql-source):

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("server_host/instance_name", "database_name"),
    Sql  = "truncate table [target_table]", 
    RunSql  = Value.NativeQuery(Source, Sql)
in
    RunSql
```

When I run this, it fails and gives the error message "Expression.Error:  This native database query isn't currently supported."

Is it possible to execute the TRUNCATE TABLE statement in Power Query against SQL Server, and if so, how?

Comment: *I'd like to use Microsoft Power Query to truncate a SQL Server table.*  --  Why...?  It sounds like there is a different requirement you have here that we may be able to help you with, whereas you are currently asking for help on how to make what you think the solution is work?

Comment: @iamdave Here's my use case:  I want to refresh a SQL Server table with data from a text file that is in a complex format (from SAP).  I'd like to use PowerQuery in Excel to graphically manipulate a text file that has data.  Once I extract the needed data, I'd like to first truncate the target table in SQL Server, and then load the newly extracted data.  I know there are many tools to load data into SQL Server, but I want to leverage Power Query to manipulate the text file.

Comment: How are you going to load the data into SQL Server once it is transformed?  Can you not use that tool (which presumably is capable of and actaully intended for *loading* data rather than *querying* data...?) to execute the `truncate` before doing the load?

Comment: I'd like a pipeline that does the following:  1.  Open file and transform.  2.  Truncate target table.  3.  Load new data.  I was hoping to do all in Excel.  I guess I could use ADO, but I wanted to leverage my existing connection/conde.

Comment: This is what SSIS is for, which comes included with your SQL Server licence (assuming you aren't using Express).

Comment: SSIS is not the greatest solution because our company has implemented onerous controls over it, even in development.  To deploy a package, I need my boss' approval on a form that I need to fill out.  Also, Excel is easy to use and we already have many transformations written in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("server_host/instance_name", "database_name"),
    Sql  = "truncate table [target_table] select 1", 
    RunSql  = Value.NativeQuery(Source, Sql)
in
    RunSql
```